# Is it possible to make new forms localizable by default in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localization

I have searched and searched for an option to make all new WinForms locaziable by default.
Currently me and my team has to remember to set new forms as localizable, is there a way to do this by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own [form template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) that has this set by default.

Base it on the existing form template so you don't have to reinvent everything.

Comment: Super, just what i was looking for. Thanks